# Rails how to make example.com/post/1 to example.com/blog/post/1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a blog with root
    `root 'posts#index'`

And works best with `example.com/` to `example.com/posts`

But what I want is something like this:

`example.com/blog/posts/1`.

I've tried creating blog `Controller` and add

```
resources :blog do
resources :posts
end
```

But this is making my routes to `blog/:id/posts/:id`

Comment: do you have a relation between blog and posts?

Comment: No. i started creating from posts controller and model. then i just created a blog controller to make it `example.com/blog/post`, but can't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand upon @Sravan answer. If you have multiple routes that will start with /blog/ you might want to check [Rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).

You can add something along the lines of

```
scope '/blog' do
    resources :posts
    resources :users
    resources :images
end
```

Which will create corresponding routes under /blog/.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the relationship between the `post` and the `blog` as you mentioned, rails gives you the freedom to declare routes as our own.

so, to make the route `example.com/posts/1` to, `example.com/blog/posts/1`, just add a custom route at the last.

`get '/blog/posts/:id', to: :show, controller: 'posts'`

what this does is over rides the previous route and make this route final.

Now type rake routes and it will give the last route for you as,

`GET      /blog/posts/:id(.:format)            posts#show`

Now you can access using,

`example.com/blog/posts/1`

[Reference for rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Yes! but this is way too complicated. But i found below `42linoge's` answer a little easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace :blog do
  resources :posts
  resources :users
  resources :images
end
```

And your controller with namespace will look like this: **Blog::PostsController**